# How to identify pbix using it's file signature

Tags: c#, validation, file-upload, powerbi

I'm working on an upload feature for `.pbix` files and want to validate it using [File Signature Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-7.0#file-signature-validation) as specified. However, after checking this [article](https://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html) and others I haven't found the signature for this specific type of file.

After uploading the [Sales & Returns Sample v201912.pbix](https://github.com/microsoft/powerbi-desktop-samples/blob/main/Sample%20Reports/Sales%20%26%20Returns%20Sample%20v201912.pbix) sample to [Online Hex Editor](https://www.onlinehexeditor.com/) it gave me the following results.

[image]

I've added file size and extension validation, but I'd like to also add signature validation. I've tried different byte sizes but don't seem to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.pbix files are actually ZIP files. You can easily check that by changing the extension to .zip and extracting the contents. So according the [link](https://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html) from you post and the references in it ([ref. 1](https://petlibrary.tripod.com/ZIP.HTM), [ref. 2](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/APPNOTE/APPNOTE-6.3.9.TXT)), the signature should be `50 4B 03 04`. These bytes matches the screenshot of the hex content from your post too.